# Extract values from sql script output which are not equal to zero

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I am basically doing row counts of tables with same names between 2 different databases.

Our sql script is something like this:

```
select (select count(1) from source.abc@remotedb) - (select count(1) from target.bcd) from dual;
```

we have almost 2000 scripts similar to above.

and the output is like following:

```
select count(1) from source.abc@remotedb) - (select count(1) from target.abc
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
0

select count(1) from source.opo@remotedb) - (select count(1) from target.opo
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
26

select count(1) from source.asd@remotedb) - (select count(1) from target.asd
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-95
```

Now using using bash/shell scripting i want to print the output to a separate file  of only those three lines where the numeric value is NOT equal to 0.

Example:

```
$ cat final_result.txt

select count(1) from source.opo@remotedb) - (select count(1) from target.opo
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
26

select count(1) from source.asd@remotedb) - (select count(1) from target.asd
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-95
```

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -E -B1 '\-{0,1}[1-9][0-9]*' fileinput > final_result.txt
```

-B1: one line Before the matched line

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
egrep -B3 '^\-*[1-9]+$' fileinput > final_result.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do like this:

```
cat result_of_sql | grep -v '^$' | paste - - - | awk -F"\t" '$3!=0{print $1}'
```

Where

- `grep -v '^$'` get rid of empty lines
- `paste - - -` aggregate every 3 lines into 1 with tabs
- `awk -F"\t" '$3!=0{print $1}'` awk magic: print the expected result.